# Do I need a UK visa (South African + EU citizens)

Tags: uk

My wife and kids have EU passports and I have a South African. Do I need a visa when travelling to the UK with them, and if so - which one ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you need a visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y
You’ll need an EEA Family Permit https://www.gov.uk/family-permit to enter the UK as a visitor travelling with family members who are EEA nationals.

Comment: OR an article 10/20 card, if they're resident in the EEA